# Android run error app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: android

hi i write an app thats works on my phone (api 23,Android 6.0.1) but when i want to start the app on Geneymotion (virtual android device on api 17 )this error shows up

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

i write the app for that api but i dont know why this is happening

gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.mma.introsliderproject"

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.halysongoncalves:pugnotification:1.8.1'
    compile 'me.tatarka.support:jobscheduler:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.victor:lib:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.sd6352051:NiftyDialogEffects:v1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.discrollview:library:0.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.github.alxrm:animated-clock-icon:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: **`multiDexEnabled true`**

Comment: i add that code but now i have another error

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/text/BidiFormatter.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application level `app.gradle` add the following

1. in `dependencies`,

   ```
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
   ```
2. in `defaultConfig`

   ```
   multiDexEnabled true
   ```

If you use your own `Application` class then, change it as follows,

- *extends `Application`* to *extends `MultiDexApplication`*
- Also add this.

  ```
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
      MultiDex.install(newBase);
      super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
  }
  ```

If you don't use any custom `Application`, change your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        ... >

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your app build.gradle

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group:'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    compile.exclude group:'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```